# What is the Google Cloud Storage public read uri?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I created a google cloud storage bucket and set it's ACL to public-read.

What is the unauthenticated URI to objects in my new bucket?

I tried this:

`https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/my-new-bucket/my-object`

as outlined [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/request-endpoints#typical) but it returns "Not found"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example public object URL: http://pub.storage.googleapis.com/shakespeare/rose.txt

Other examples of the same resource:

https://storage.googleapis.com/pub/shakespeare/rose.txt
https://pub.storage.googleapis.com/shakespeare/rose.txt

Our JSON API also allows for object downloads, but it's not designed for serving web requests.These URLs will usually involve some redirects and/or the server instructing the browser to treat the object as an attachment:

https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/pub/o/shakespeare%2Frose.txt?alt=media

Comment: I see, those work. For some reason even though I changed the ACL of the entire bucket to public-read, when I upload objects, they are still not public-readable

Answer (score 1):

To access public objects, you need to edit its permissions [by following these steps](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public) either for an individual object or a group of objects. After you set your permissions, a link icon will appear in the public access column. That's the public URL for your object.

Comment: But if I made the entire bucket public-read, shouldn't anything I then upload into it be public..?

Comment: I understand that by default, new objects are not set with the public permission automatically. Therefore, you'll need to set the permission with the aforementioned steps

Comment: but what is the point of making a bucket public if you have to explicitly set an object as public when you upload it